# What happens to the non-unicode API functions when I define UNICODE and/or _UNICODE?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode

In MS Visual Studio, when you do not set the character set, the likes of `AfxMessageBox()` (and countless other API functions) will happily accept a `CStringA` argument. But the moment you set the character set to Unicode, what appear to be the very same functions will only accept `CStringW` arguments.

Now this is precisely what the documentation says should happen... but...
where exactly did those non-Unicode API functions go? Are they still there to be linked to under other names (`AfxMessageBoxA()` perhaps?). By what magic does one API disappear and another one appear in its place... or alternatively... by what mischievous hacker trick can one make them reappear? And if it is possible to make them reappear in the presence of Unicode, should one (judiciously) use such hacker mischief?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of AfxMessageBox() in afxwin.h is:

```
   int AFXAPI AfxMessageBox(LPCTSTR lpszText, UINT nType = MB_OK,
                            UINT nIDHelp = 0);
```

It is LPCTSTR that adapts the string type.  If you compile with UNICODE in effect then it is an alias for `const wchar_t*`.  Without it is `const char*`.  There is no AfxMessageBoxA() version.

This is very different from the way the winapi functions work, necessarily so since this is a C++ function that mangles differently.  Technically they could have provided another overload of the function, they didn't.  You'll also have a different link demand, you need to link the non-Unicode version of the MFC library to keep the linker happy.  Notable is that it is deprecated and no longer ships with recent VS editions, but still available (right now) as a separate download.

This should answer your question, it doesn't go anywhere, it simply doesn't exist.  Mixing cannot work, you'll need A2W() to convert the string.  You could of course simply write your own overload if necessary.

Comment: It's the "You'll also have a different link demand" part that confuses me: there is no different link demand - it links the same whether UNICODE is defined or not. This is some kind of advanced magic - the kind that allows types to be defined neither strictly at compile time, nor at runtime, but at some unclear place in the middle. Because when you link, you appear to be linking to some clever sort of precompiled leopard that is capable of changing its spots. Magic. Or maybe it just looks like a leopard, but is an illusion. That's magic too. I'm impressed, but still confused! :-)

Comment: I don't doubt your answer for a second, BTW, I just haven't managed to fully understand it yet :-)

Comment: This is done automatically, the MFC source code contains #pragma comment to ensure the correct .lib is always linked.  You can tell because you never explicitly told the linker what specific .lib to link in your project.

Comment: Thanks - that makes more sense now - nothing is magic when you know how the trick is done.